# How can I fix my wordpress "lost password" link?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, passwords

My wordpress password link is completely missing from my admin login page. I used a link I found on the web, that at least lets me access the page to enter my email or user name to reset it.

when I enter in a my user name or a (subscribers) user name it displays a message stating

"password reset is not allowed for this user"

What else can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methinks, you using **Ldap** plugin with Wordpress or MU. Please **delete ldap folder** in plugins folder.

Comment: @faith SARI --What exactly is a Idap folder , and what will be deleted in the process? ---- I don't want to lose any content or data

Comment: Are you using Wordpress MU or normal WP?

Comment: okey, you are beginner :) Methinks, your sistem is normal WP. **1.** Connect FTP, **2.** Go ´wp-content/plugins/´ **3.** Delete **ldap** folder.

Comment: or if is not exist in plugins folder please add your plugins list.

Comment: @ faith SARI -- stay with me here :) I can access my file manager through my host (hostgator) and delete it there right? And by deleting that particular folder , will i lose any content that may be vauable?

Comment: I have a SSL installed will that be affected?

Comment: @chrishughes first not **faith**, my name is **fatih** :) i'm fallowing this proccess. you don't lose anything. but for safe you can rename this folder only. **ldap** to **ldap_**

Comment: @chrishughes no damage to the SSL

Comment: Sorry for that mix up, And I checked my plugins file wp-content/pugins , but no Ldap folder. Just my list of plugins

Comment: Okey, please add your plugins list to this question. I'll examine your plugins for issue.

Comment: Akismet---
BulletProof Security---
Contact Form---
Custom Favicon---
Custom Sidebars---
Hello Dolly---
Insert PHP---
Jetpack by WordPress.com---
Lightweight Social Icons---
MOJO Marketplace---
Nav Menu Roles---
Page Builder by SiteOrigin---
PageLines Updater---
SB Welcome Email Editor---
Wordfence Security---
WP Admin Bar Removal--
WPJobBoard--
WP Product Review--
WP Super Cache---
 [WPJB] Force Title---
 [WPJB] Terms and Conditions

Comment: Your problem in bottom of the page. This is feature of last BulletProof Security plugin. http://www.ait-pro.com/aitpro-blog/4780/bulletproof-security-pro/whats-new-in-bulletproof-security-pro-5-8/ Please de-active it and try again. For deactiving rename plugin folder.

Comment: Wow, so its only a feature , not a plugin error . Meaning I can go and modify the plugins setting to adjust this issue

Comment: we still get it for some users not all. Plugin list: backupwordpress, bbpress, breadcrumb,column-shortcodes,contact-form-7,custom-content-shortcode,custom-sidebars,download-manager,google-analytics-for-wordpress,insert-php,members,menu-items-visibility-control,news-manager,pagerestrict,pie-register,put,really-simple-captcha,search-everything,tinymce-advanced,widget-settings-importexport,wordpress-importer,wordpress-seo,wp-lightbox-2,wp-math-captcha,wpdm-download-button,wpdm-extended-shortcodes,wpdm-tinymce-button